# Stiefel manifolds & number of free parameters

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, stiefel-manifolds

Recently, we got introduced to the Stiefel manifold $V_k(\mathbb R^n)$, that is, the set of orthonormal $k$-frames in $\mathbb R^n$. In particular, we discussed the case for $k=2$, $V_2(\mathbb R^n) \subset \mathbb R^{2n}$. Thus, any $2$-frame consists of two $n$-dimensional orthonormal vectors $x,y\in \mathbb R^{n}$. We obtain the tree equations

\begin{align}
\Vert x\Vert^2 &= 1 \\
\Vert y\Vert^2 &= 1 \\
\langle x,y\rangle &= 0
\end{align}

where $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ denotes the standard scalar product. However, we then said that we should expect $2n-3$ free parameters $$\underbrace{(n-1)}_{\text{param. for}\ x}+ \underbrace{(n-2)}_{\text{param. for}\ y} = 2n-3$$

But I don't understand what exactly is meant here, when we say $2n-3$ parameters. How can one (geometrically and algebraically) verify this? I'm assuming that this somehow relates to the $n\times k$ (here $n\times 2)$ matrices of rank $2$, but how exactly?

Sorry for the very vague question, unfortunately, we quickly skimmed over this topic and this is all we've written down. I also tried to look it up in all of my books but I didn't finy anything other than the definition of Stiefel manifolds in Kosinski's *Differential Manifolds*.

Comment: It’s the regular value theorem. This is the dimension of the manifold. You’re imposing constraints on the space of rank $2$ matrices, so I don’t get your point.

Comment: Presumably, the number of "free parameters" of $V_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ just refers to the dimension of $V_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$, which, as Ted Shifrin notes, can be deduced from the regular value theorem. Intuitively, one can think of choosing vectors one at a time: the first can be any unit vector, so it corresponds to a point in $S^{n-1}$; the second must also be orthogonal to the first, so it must be chosen from a $(n-2)$-sphere, and so on.

Comment: You have $2n$ unknowns and $3$ equality constraints. Hence, $2n-3$ degrees of freedom is not exactly surprising. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, they were indeed very helpful. Thanks for the geometric clarification Kajelad.